# Swift header doesn't contain two methods

Tags: swift

I'm defining two methods in a Swift class:

```
public func send(data: [UInt8], length: Int){
    let queueObject = WriteQueueObject(data: NSData(bytes: data, length: length), userInfo: nil)
    queue.append(queueObject) //queue is of type [WriteQueueObject]
}

public func send(data: [UInt8], length: Int, userInfo: [String:AnyObject]){
    let queueObject = WriteQueueObject(data: NSData(bytes: data, length: length), userInfo: userInfo)
    queue.append(queueObject)
}
```

Everything is working fine except these two methods are not being exported to `ProductName-Swift.h` Why?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in the Objective-C / Swift bridge, but it looks like arrays of `UInt8` (or of any other byte-length-specific integer) aren't compatible with Objective-C. I say it may be a bug, since `UInt8`s by themselves are fine, and the "[Swift Type Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_35)" section of *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* doesn't say anything about it.

Here's a workaround:

```
public func send(data: [UInt], length: Int) {
    let dataConverted = data.map { UInt8($0) }
    let queueObject = WriteQueueObject(data: NSData(bytes: dataConverted, length: length), userInfo: nil)
    queue.append(queueObject) //queue is of type [WriteQueueObject]
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I think too that this must be a bug. I'll try your workaround.